# Python Multi-Processing - Spawns only two processess

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

I have a python code that needs to do some processing on approximately 1MM rows. We are using python's multiprocessing module

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

    rows_per_workload = 250000
    num_loads = math.ceil(data_df.shape[0]/float(rows_per_workload))
    agents =num_loads
    print ('Num Loads ', num_loads , ' DF Shape ', data_df.shape[0])
    split_df = np.array_split(data_df, num_loads) # List of DFs

    with Pool(processes=agents) as pool:
            result = pool.starmap(func=work,iterable=zip(split_df, [skey_data, skey_data]))
            result = pandas.concat(result)

def work(argdata, argmaster):
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())
```

Even though we are expecting 4 processes to be spawned from this line
    `with Pool(processes=agents) as pool:` we see only 2 processes.  When i run this code we see only two PIDs

```
parent process: 19652
process id: 12936
parent process: 19652
process id: 14836
```

what am i missing please..

Regards

Bala

Comment: The problem is `zip(split_df, [skey_data, skey_data])`, which gives a list contains only two tuples.

Comment: Additional to @Sraw's observation, unless you want to **limit** the number of pool processes, suggest not specifying the number.  The default is to create as a many workers as you have cores in your system, which is pragmatically the best you can hope for in terms of parallelism.  Anything higher than that, and your system will actually process slower due to context switching, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Sraw and hunteke. The two tuples were the problem. Once i increase them, i get more processess.. Thank you so much
Hunteke, thanks for your caution. This code is in my development environment and eventually be parameterized. We have no intention to reduce the number of workers, however, we may end of having less than the number of cores. We are intending that to be a configuration variable. Thank you so much for your note. Highly appreciate that.

Comment: In Python 3, `/` produces a float, so no need to convert either operand.